# Decorating a function with a method (with arbitrary arguments)

Tags: python, function, methods, decorator, python-decorators

#### References

Before writing this question, I have referred some of the following interesting questions and feel that this scenario is not explained/covered:

- [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators) (especially answer #2)
- [How to decorate a method inside a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367514/how-to-decorate-a-method-inside-a-class)
- [Python decorators in classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263451/python-decorators-in-classes)
- [Python Class Based Decorator with parameters that can decorate a method or a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416947/python-class-based-decorator-with-parameters-that-can-decorate-a-method-or-a-fun) (close but not exactly what I am asking)

I have a `function` as follows:

```
def simple_function():
    print 'this is a simple_function'
```

And, I have the following `class` with some `methods`

```
class Test:

    def Test_method_1(self, func, args=None, kwargs=None):
        print 'this is Test::Test_method_1'
        <execute some instructions here>

    def Test_method_2(self):
        print 'this is Test::Test_method_2'
```

I am using `Test_method_1` and `simple_function` as follows:

```
t = Test()
t.Test_method_1(simple_function)
```

Say if the `simple_function` takes arbitrary arguments, then the `Test_method_1` is called as follows:

```
def simple_function(a, b, c, d=f, g=h):
    print 'this is a simple_function'

t = Test()
t.Test_method_1(simple_function, args=[a, b, c], kwargs={d:f, g:h})
```

Now, I want to use `Test_method_2` as a `decorator version` of `Test_method_1`. So the `simple_function` definition can be written as follows:

```
t = Test()

@t.Test_method_2
def simple_function():
    print 'this is a simple_function'
```

Note: the `Test_method_2` will call `Test_method_1` with appropriate arguments.

#### Now the questions:

- 1 - Is this possible?
- 2 - If possible, how do the name of the decorated function (here `simple_function`) will be passed as a argument to `Test_method_2` (including the `self`)?
- 3 - [Here is the killer question, I believe] I want to pass arbitrary arguments to both `Test_method_2` (the decorator) and  `simple_function` (the function being decorated) - `*args and **kwargs` - How should the `Test_method_2` be defined to receive arguments (including the `self`)?

The usage of `Test_method_2` as a decorator for `simple_function` with arbitrary arguments for both is as follows:

```
t = Test()
@t.Test_method_2(a, b, c, d, e=f, g=h)
def simple_function(x, y, z, n=m):
    print 'this is a simple_function'
```

Comment: This is what ``flask`` does with ``@app.route('/path')`` so it is possible and I've done similar with ``lxml`` by decorating a function that will be called for when an Xpath matches, something like ``@xml.matches('//Some/Element')``

Comment: Have you tried it?  Why don't you try it and see if it works, then ask questions about what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible. All the `@decorator` syntax does is define the function that follows, then call the decorator, passing in the function that followed and replacing the reference to that function with whatever was returned.

So the following:

```
@foo
def bar():
    pass
```

is translated to:

```
def bar():
    pass
bar = foo(bar)
```

This means that your `t.Test_method_2()` method must expect one argument, the to-be-decorated function, and return something callable:

```
import functools

def Test_method_2(self, func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
        print 'Wrapped function name:', func.__name__
        return func(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

would be the minimal decorator that returns a wrapper function, and prints the name of the wrapped function when called. It doesn't matter what the argument is *called*; I used `func` here but it can be any legal python identifier.

The `self` is the standard part of the method signature. Because you are referencing `Test_method_2` on an instance `t`, Python automatically takes care of the `self` parameter for you as it does with all methods.

Anything after `@` is just an expression. So if you use the syntax:

```
@t.Test_method_2(a, b, c, d, e=f, g=h)
```

then `Test_method_2()` should instead return a decorator function. One extra level of scope nesting should do that:

```
def Test_method_2(self, *args, **kw):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*wrapperargs, **wrapperkw):
            fargs = args + wrapperargs
            fkw = dict(kw)
            fkw.update(wrapperkw)
            return func(*fargs, **fkw)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Deconstructing this:

```
@t.Test_method_2(5, 6, 7, 8, baz='spam', ham='eggs')
def simple_function(x, y, z, n=m):
    print 'this is a simple_function'
```

The part after the `@`, `t.Test_method_2(5, 6, 7, 8, baz='spam', ham='eggs')` returns the nested function `decorator`:

```
@decorator
def simple_function(x, y, z, n=m):
    print 'this is a simple_function'
```

which python then turns into:

```
simple_function = decorator(simple_function)
```

and `decorator(func)` returns `wrapper(*wrapperargs, **wrapperkw)`.

Calling `simple_function(1, 2, foo='bar')` then results in a call to `wrapper(1, 2, foo='bar')` which calls the *original* `simple_function()` with `fargs = [5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2]` and `fkw = {'baz': 'spam', 'ham': 'eggs', 'foo': 'bar'}` passed in as positional and keyword arguments.

The class decorator pattern you see in the linked questions works in a similar way; the expression after the `@` returns something that is called; instead of a nested function a class instance is being created instead. It's just two different approaches to storing state for the decorator to use.

The nested functions is a little more compact to write, while using a class gives you more introspection options than a nested scope.