# decorating methods of a class based on a pattern

Tags: python, python-2.7

hi i a class like this:

```
def Foo:
   def calc(self):
      print "calc"

   def on_get(self):  
      print "on get"

   def on_post(self):  
      print "on post"
```

I want to inject a pdb tracer in any method of the class that starts with `on_` , so i thought of writing a decorator to do that.This is what i have until now.

```
def debuggable(cls):
   from types import FunctionType

   def pdb_injector(view):
       def injector_wrapper():
           import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
           view()
       return injector_wrapper

   class wrapped(cls):
       views = [x for x,y in cls.__dict__.items() if type(y) == FunctionType and 'on_' in x]
       for view in views:
           _view = getattr(cls,view)
           _view = pdb_injector(_view)
           setattr(cls ,view, _view)
   return wrapped
```

When i do call `Foo.on_get()` after adding `@debuggable` to the `Foo` class. i get this error:

> TypeError: injector_wrapper() takes no arguments (1 given).

why am i getting this error?

Comment: Methods have to take `self` as their first parameter. If your `injector_wrapper()` is going to replace a method, it needs to accept a `self` parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decorate a method inside a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367514/how-to-decorate-a-method-inside-a-class)

Comment: @khelwood instead of doing `self=None` as given in the linked answer can i instead do `injector_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)`?

Comment: @anekix I'll have to disagree with khelwood (and with the linked answer) here - as far as I'm concerned, using `*args` and `*kwargs` is the proper way to write a generic decorator wrapper that can be applied to any function/method - unless you know you're going to target methods only and you want to access `self` in the wrapper in which case you want `(self, *args, **kw)`

Comment: What @brunodesthuilliers said.

Comment: @anekix also don't forget to pass the arguments to the wrapped function !-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yeah i figured that out. thanks :)