# Python decorator crashing even though its code is solid, can't understand why

Tags: python, class, crash, decorator, python-decorators

So I wrote a function called 'anonimize' that gets a string and returns that string with some details blacked-out, using regex.
The function works fine on its own, but I tried to turn it into a decorator and things went south and got so many crashes so many times.
I am learning decorators and would really like to understand what I am doing wrong.
In this unsuccessful version I got "TypeError: BankApplication.anonimize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callable'".

```
import re


class BankApplication:

    def __init__(self, bank_name):
        self.name = bank_name

    '''
      Perform anonimization to the text data:
      1. Remove possible account numbers (more than 5 digits in a row)
      2. Remove possible email addresses
      3. Remove possible First + Last names (two consequtive words 
         starting from upper case, but not divided by .)
   '''

    def anonimize(func):
        def inner(arg):
            ret = func(arg)
            print(
                re.sub("[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+", "***", re.sub("\S+@\S+\.\S+", "***", re.sub("\d{5,}", "***", arg))))
            return ret

        return inner

    @anonimize
    def feedback(self, feedback_text):
        print("Called feedback")

    @anonimize
    def log_info(self, info_to_log):
        print("Called feedback")


bank = BankApplication("Bank")
bank.feedback("Name: John Doe\nE-mail: johndoe@fakemail.com\nAccount number: 911911911.")
```

Comment: I corrected the indentation

Answer (score 0):

`anonimize` shouldn't be an instance method of `BankApplication`, it doesn't even accept `self`. Define it outside of the class.

EDIT: I've also suggested `@staticmethod`, but it wouldn't work either, see @James's answer.

Comment: and `arg` should be `*arg` where defined and `arg[1]` where used.

Comment: @luk2302, yeah, ideally decorator should `def inner(*args, **kwargs)`, but I'm not sure if I agree with you in this case. It seems like the decorator is designed for these one-argument methods specifically, and not for general use. `arg[1]` wouldn't work in the general case anyway, because it assumes that the string parameter always comes first. If I were the OP, I would simply apply a string-transforming function to the argument inside of these methods, instead of decorating them. Still one line, but simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `anonimize` out of the class.  Why?

The first argument that gets passed to a standard method is always the owning object itself (the `self` argument is the standard syntax, but you can call it anything).

You cannot use it as a static method because decorators are run when the code is defined.  You won't be able to reference the owning object because it won't have been instantiated yet.

```
import re

def anonimize(func):
    def inner(arg):
        ret = func(arg)
        print(
            re.sub("[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+", "***", re.sub("\S+@\S+\.\S+", "***", re.sub("\d{5,}", "***", arg))))
        return ret
    return inner

class BankApplication:

    def __init__(self, bank_name):
        self.name = bank_name

    '''
      Perform anonimization to the text data:
      1. Remove possible account numbers (more than 5 digits in a row)
      2. Remove possible email addresses
      3. Remove possible First + Last names (two consequtive words 
         starting from upper case, but not divided by .)
   '''

    ...
```

Comment: Interesting note about `@staticmethod`, I didn't think about it. I'll edit my answer

Comment: thanks :) I thought that as well, this was the way the teacher wanted us to do. Anyway, I got the decorator out of the class, now I am getting: "TypeError: anonimize.<locals>.inner() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: @swapman [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367514/how-to-decorate-a-method-inside-a-class) should help you with the TypeError

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this was the **wrong version I posted**:

```
def anonimize(func):
    def inner(text):
        print(re.sub("[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+", "***", re.sub("\S+@\S+\.\S+", "***", re.sub("\d{5,}", "***", text))))
        return func(text)
    return inner
```

And this is **the way it should have been**:

```
def anonimize(func):
    def inner(self, text):
        text = re.sub("[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+", "***", re.sub("\S+@\S+\.\S+", "***", re.sub("\d{5,}", "***", text)))
        return func(self, text)
    return inner
```

Comment: I asked what caused my program crash. The answer was that I didn't use 'self' when defining a method inside a class.