# How to use decorator, defined inside the class, with no warnings

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, decorator

I've defined decorator inside the class and trying to use it in the same class.
I've created the decorator according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367514/how-to-decorate-a-method-inside-a-class) topic. But PyCharm tells me, that this is veeery sus way to do this.
Here is the code:

```
import sys
from typing import Callable


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.smile = ':P'

    def handle_exception(func: Callable):
        def handle_exception_wrapper(self=None, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                return self.shutdown()
            except Exception as error:
                self.shutdown(error)

        return handle_exception_wrapper

    @handle_exception
    def some_function(self) -> None:
        print('some suspicious function is working')
        raise RuntimeError('Break Runtime - all be fine')
    
    def shutdown(error=None):
        if error:
            print('error:', error)
            print('function collapsed')
        else:
            print('good-boy function completed the task')
        print('goodbye', self.smile)
        sys.exit(1)

    


test = TestClass()
test.some_function()
```

And IDE warnings:
[image: IDE warniings]

And this code works (bc of decorator passing a class object quietly). But looks kinda sus and "inPEPful".

Long story short, is it possible to define and use decorator inside the class beautifully? (One thing is important that I want to access class methods inside the decorator).

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: You probably need to add more type hints, using `typing.ParamSpec` to "copy" the signature of `func` to the signature of `handle_exception_wrapper`. That way, `PyCharm` will be able to tell what the "real" static type of `initialize_api` is after `handle_exception` is done with it.

Comment: `self=None` and `*args` together are a bit weird, as there's no way to let `self` take a default value of `None` *and* pass arguments to `*args`. Either `self` is `None` and `args` will be empty, or `self` will consume one of the positional arguments.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Barmar, sorry, but screenshot is necessary, for better understanding of IDE warnings. I've also attached the code example and corrected the screenshot and the text.

Comment: @toyotaSupra, i've attached the code :P

Comment: Can you remove screenshot?

Comment: @toyotaSupra, sure, but I wanted to show the IDE hints and warnings on it...

Comment: Ok! That fine with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't confidently tell you that this does what you want it to, but you can fix the PyCharm errors by making `handle_exception` a static method, and adding a `self` argument to `shutdown` and a newline at the end. Here is the file, PyCharm warning-free version:

```
import sys
from typing import Callable


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.smile = ':P'

    @staticmethod
    def handle_exception(func: Callable):
        def handle_exception_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                return self.shutdown()
            except Exception as error:
                self.shutdown(error)

        return handle_exception_wrapper

    @handle_exception
    def some_function(self) -> None:
        print('some suspicious function is working')
        raise RuntimeError('Break Runtime - all be fine')

    def shutdown(self, error=None):
        if error:
            print('error:', error)
            print('function collapsed')
        else:
            print('good-boy function completed the task')
        print('goodbye', self.smile)
        sys.exit(1)


test = TestClass()
test.some_function()
```

Tested on PyCharm 2023.3.4 Community Edition, Python 3.11.7 on Windows 11.

Comment: This looks like a working solution. Thank you for the coded answer! I will use it instead of my current solution - I extended the decorator outside the class and removed `self` from the hardcoded arguments (just call `args[0].shutdown(error)` - not beautiful but also works).